# Как на С++ WinAPI узнать имя всех процессов или процесса, удерживающих файл?

Tags: c++, winapi

Как на С++ WinAPI узнать имена всех процессов или процесса, удерживающих/удерживающего файл?
Как это вообще делается?
Можете привести примеры, пожалуйста.

Я только учусь и буду очень вам благодарен!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1180508/240512

Comment: MSDN.WhiteKnight
, спасибо дорогой!.. А если открыт с параметром FileShare=0 - как тогда быть? Как освободить?

Comment: Вы попробуйте применить способ, тогда все станет ясно. При работе с именем файла все должно работать и с FileShare=0.

Comment: Отправьте пожалуйста ответом ваш код - я его выберу. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого используется Restart Manager API. Принцип как и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1180508/240512), только работаем с именем файла, а не с дескриптором:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <restartmanager.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Rstrtmgr.lib")

void PrintProcesses(const WCHAR* file) {
    DWORD hSess = 0;    
    WCHAR key[50] = L"MySession";
    DWORD res;

    res = RmStartSession(&hSess, 0, key);

    if (res != 0) {
        wprintf(L"Cannot start session\n");
        return;
    }

    LPCWSTR filenames[] = { file };
    res = RmRegisterResources(hSess, 1, filenames, 0, NULL, 0, NULL);

    if (res != 0) {
        wprintf(L"Cannot register resource\n");
        return;
    }

    UINT procInfoNeeded;
    UINT procInfo = 10;
    DWORD rebootReasons;
    RM_PROCESS_INFO info[10];
    res = RmGetList(hSess, &procInfoNeeded, &procInfo, info, &rebootReasons);

    if (res != 0) {
        wprintf(L"Cannot get list of processes\n");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < procInfo; i++)
        wprintf(L"%u: %s\n", info[i].Process.dwProcessId, info[i].strAppName);
}

int main() {
    PrintProcesses(L"c:\\Test\\file.txt");
    getchar();
}
```